Must shell extension be not in the main STA?
I have a shell extension dll that adds a menu item in the context menu. But it can only run after I add the value ThreadingModel=Apartment in the InProcServer32 key of registry. Without the value, the dll cannot be loaded. I wonder if there is a requirement for the threading model of a shell extension dll. Which apartment does the thread instantiating the COM object in the shell extension dll belong to?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers#registering-shell-extension-handlers says "Use the Apartment threading model."

That explains why it does not work without the value ThreadingModel=Apartment. Thanks, @SimonMourier.

I think maybe it is because all shell extensions need to be run in separated threads which are not the GUI thread of Explorer.

In general apartment requirement is related to UI-bound actions which is the case in general with shell extensions, but you can run and talk to objects in separate threads w/o STA ("apartment" in registry) requirement, provided there are proxy/stubs for all interfaces involved (to the cost of marshaling method parameters and return value forth and back). Not sure all interfaces involved in shell extensions are marshalable.
